# How to import ethereum account in web3 if I know address and private key?

Tags: node.js, web3js

I start ganache-gui and see lot of accounts, they have private keys and mnemonic phrase. Then I connect to this testnet with nodejs and web3 1.x.x, so my wallet.length is 0. I want to import all wallet from ganache by mnemonic phrase or better import one address using private key. Could I do this? I tried `web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);` but returns new account. How does it work? Metamask can do this just by privateKey.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to access you ganache accounts in your code..right?

Comment: Right. I also want to know how to import any account knowing its private key, as metamask does.

Comment: Could you also please upvote the answer, if it served your purpose? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, reputation not enough for upvote. I am new user there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the ganache accounts, you have to do the following:

```
    const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
    const Web3 = require('web3');

   //ganache client running on port 7545
    var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));

    const getAccounts = async () =>{

   //To get all accounts
    let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    //To get accounts with private key
    let account = await web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x'+privateKey);
    //privateKey is the key that you get from Ganache client
    }

    getAccounts();
```

Comment: Private key should always start with 0x.